# Springfox swagger 2 not working with Spring Boot 1.5: HTTP 404 not found at /v2/api-docs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a Spring Boot project with springfox-swagger-2 as dependency.

Versions used:

- Spring Boot: 1.5.9.RELEASE
- springfox-swagger-2: 2.7.0

This is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket api = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
        api
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();

            api.apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .globalOperationParameters(Lists.newArrayList(new ParameterBuilder()
                .name("Example api info")
                .description("description")
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .parameterType("parameter type example").build()))
            ;
        return api;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("name", "url", "email");
        Collection<VendorExtension> vendorExtensions = new ArrayList<>();
        return new ApiInfo("title", "description", "version", "termsOfServiceUrl", contact, "license", "licenseUrl", vendorExtensions);
    }
}
```

The application starts correctly, but the url `/v2/api-docs` gets an **HTTP 404 Not Found**

Even the /swagger-ui.html is not available adding the dependency for springfox-swagger-ui

The bootstrap log doesn't report any error.

I already tried to find the answer on other similar questions but any of them is working!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: springfox-swagger-ui dependency is added?

Comment: of course, the version is the same of springfox-swagger-2

Comment: Hello @AlessandroC Are you using Spring Security, if yes you may need to add configuration for it

Comment: @Patel Romil Hi, yes I have Spring Security, and I already have a configuration for it!

Comment: Hello  @AlessandroC Please have a look at an answer which works fine for me

Comment: Solved with the answer that I posted below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
   @Bean
   public Docket apiDocket() {

       Docket docket =  new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.."))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

       return docket;

    } 
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
              .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
        }

    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

             http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
             .permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

    @Override 
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't' work on my project... Furthermore, I have just tried to disable the security on the application.properties and it doesn't work even with Spring security OFF, so it can't be an issue related to Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to yourapplication.properties

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the way to make it work.

The springfox-swagger-2 implementation has a `@Controller` within the class `springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller`.

This class implements the mapping for the url `"/v2/api-docs"` with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = DEFAULT_URL,
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HAL_MEDIA_TYPE })
@PropertySourcedMapping(
    value = "${springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path}",
    propertyKey = "springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Json> getDocumentation(
    @RequestParam(value = "group", required = false) String swaggerGroup,
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

  String groupName = Optional.fromNullable(swaggerGroup).or(Docket.DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME);
  Documentation documentation = documentationCache.documentationByGroup(groupName);
  if (documentation == null) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Json>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
  Swagger swagger = mapper.mapDocumentation(documentation);
  UriComponents uriComponents = componentsFrom(servletRequest, swagger.getBasePath());
  swagger.basePath(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(uriComponents.getPath()) ? "/" : uriComponents.getPath());
  if (isNullOrEmpty(swagger.getHost())) {
    swagger.host(hostName(uriComponents));
  }
  return new ResponseEntity<Json>(jsonSerializer.toJson(swagger), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you can see, the RequestMapping expects a parameter named `"group"`.
So, if you call the `"/v2/api-docs"` url without the `"group"` parameter, the documentation obtained is null because there are no documentations in the cache for the key `""` (empty String).

I solved adding a custom Filter implemented in this way:

```
@Component
public class SwaggerFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String group = req.getParameter("group");

        if (req.getServletPath().equals("/v2/api-docs") && group==null) {
            res.sendRedirect("api-docs?group=default");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

The mechanism is simple: without the `"group"` parameter, there is a redirect with the `"default"` group parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon an **HTTP 404 Not Found** for `/v2/api-docs` (but during a unit test) as part of migrating Spring Boot from version 2.0.4.RELEASE to version 2.1.6.RELEASE. The unit test passed before the "upgrade".

The unit test class had the following annotations:

```
@Category(UnitIntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

and the test configuration was defined as an inner class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(value = BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public static class TestSwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("the.package.we.want"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
}
```

The fix was to specify the `TestSwaggerConfiguration` in the `@ContextConfiguration`, e.g.:

```
@Category(UnitIntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfiguration.class, GenerateDocumentationTest.TestSwaggerConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

As a side note, before hitting the HTTP 404 I also had to specify

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

in the `application-test.properties` as per the [Spring Boot 2.1 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding).

Answer (score 0):

In case the person stuck is a noob like me, make sure you have run the ***Maven Install*** command after adding the dependencies in the pom.xml file.